# Powershell - How to optimize photos without losing important data

Tags: image, powershell, photo

A few month ago, I wrote a PowerShell script to reduce photo size (using HighQualityBicubic setting).
It's cool but I have two problems :

1. this script create a new photo and all metadata (exif) are lost :'( I really like to keep data like "Date taken", GPS coordonate, and camera model.
2. some photos need have rotate exif data (.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0]), and the photo created are rotated, so I have new photos upside down

Here is the script :

```
    Get-ChildItem -Include "*.jpg" | ? {
        $OldBitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $_.FullName
        $NewBitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $OldBitmap.Width,$OldBitmap.Height
        $g=[System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($NewBitmap)
        $g.InterpolationMode = [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode]::HighQualityBicubic
        $g.DrawImage($OldBitmap, 0, 0, $OldBitmap.Width, $OldBitmap.Height)
        $name=$_.DirectoryName+"\"+$_.name+".new"
        $NewBitmap.Save($name, ([system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::jpeg))
        $NewBitmap.Dispose()
        $OldBitmap.Dispose()
        $g.Dispose()
    }
```

Please help (and sorry for my poor english :D)

Comment: As a non-Windows user, my suggestion would be either to use **ImageMagick** which will do all that for you, or use `exiftool` to copy-forward the EXIF data from your original to your new image. But I don't use Windows so there may well be better ways.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Mark, but I need to script it because I have a lot of photos with different EXIF data

Comment: Both of those suggestions can be scripted.

Comment: ive read something in another so-post which lead me here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FC_SysAdmin/5.0.0/Content/public%5CGet-FileMetaData.ps1 - not sure how you can write it though

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mark, I did it.

I used :

`exiftool.exe -Orientation -S $OldFile.FullName` to detect the actual orientation

`$OldBitmap.rotateflip("Rotate90FlipNone")` to rotate

`exiftool.exe -tagsFromFile $OldFile.FullName $NewFilePath -x EXIF:Orientation -ThumbnailImage= -overwrite_original` to copy EXIF data exept orientation

I didn't use **ImageMagick** but I saved it with my tools :)

Have a nice day